# Get category product with minimal price of product in each category (Django querysets)

Tags: python, django

I want to get from database only 3 categories with lowest price product in each category so i tried to do this

```
Category.objects.get(id=1).category_product.all().values('price').order_by('price')[0]

Category.objects.get(id=2).category_product.all().values('price').order_by('price')[0]

Category.objects.get(id=3).category_product.all().values('price').order_by('price')[0]
```

How to simplify this queryset, get three categories with lowest price of product in each category? Get with one request

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, related_name='category_product')

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: is the price field defined on the product model?

Comment: yes i just removed sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
Category.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3]).category_product.order_by('price').values('id', 'price')[:3]
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.